# Which method is faster to get a single post?

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, get-post

If I want to get only a single post with the featured thumbnail.

Which of the function is better to use (for the performance) `get_post` or `WP_Query`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the article »[Optimize WordPress Queries](https://thomasgriffin.io/optimize-wordpress-queries/)« by Thomas Griffin.

Comment: I very much doubt there is any noticeable difference but I use `WP_Query` always for the sake of consistency and clarity. `get_posts()` is really just a wrapper around `WP_Query`.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I tested both `get_post` and `WP_Query` on a blog with ~3k posts (to fetch all posts at once) and `get_post` is actually faster but you are right, it's not noticeable. I ran 100 times and the average difference between both is nearly 2-8 milliseconds. So I think I will also stick to `WP_Query` for the sake of consistency and clarity. :)

Comment: Run `WP_Query` with the exact arguments that `get_posts` pushes though. It doesn't make sense that a wrapper would be faster, all other things being equal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WP_Query` or `get_post()`, they are both fine.

Have a look at this to learn why **you should NOT use `query_posts()`** and how the other two affect variables etc.: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)